# Cocoa osx: Can't resolve a crashing issue reported by crashlytic

Tags: cocoa, crash, crashlytics

This is the following crash that a few users (not me) are experiencing according to crashlytics.

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AppKit                         0x7fff42f66454 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 109
1  AppKit                         0x7fff42f6633c -[NSApplication reportException:] + 953
2  AppKit                         0x7fff42c30946 -[NSApplication run] + 957
3  AppKit                         0x7fff42bffa72 NSApplicationMain + 804
4  libdyld.dylib                  0x7fff6d4dd015 start + 1

--

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  AppKit                         0x7fff42f66454 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 109
1  AppKit                         0x7fff42f6633c -[NSApplication reportException:] + 953
2  AppKit                         0x7fff42c30946 -[NSApplication run] + 957
3  AppKit                         0x7fff42bffa72 NSApplicationMain + 804
4  libdyld.dylib                  0x7fff6d4dd015 start + 1

#1. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d62e28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f520e _pthread_wqthread + 1552
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4be9 start_wqthread + 13

#2. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d62e28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f5009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4be9 start_wqthread + 13
3  (Missing)                      0x5000000000000 (Missing)

#3. io.answers.EventQueue (QOS: BACKGROUND)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d62e4fa close + 10
1  App                        0x105128b3b -[ANSWriteEventOperation main] + 4324100923
2  Foundation                     0x7fff477b68ee -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 778
3  Foundation                     0x7fff477b2917 __NSOQSchedule_f + 369
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6d4a3db8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6d4b6e81 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6d4ae733 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6d4a59a9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff6d4a5755 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f5169 _pthread_wqthread + 1387
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4be9 start_wqthread + 13

#4. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d62e28a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f5009 _pthread_wqthread + 1035
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4be9 start_wqthread + 13
3  (Missing)                      0x1b307 (Missing)

#5. com.twitter.crashlytics.mac.MachExceptionServer
0  App                        0x105119c93 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4324039827
1  App                       0x10511a08e CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4324040846
2  App                        0x1051096a4 CLSHandler + 4323972772
3  App                        0x105104c05 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4323953669
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f5661 _pthread_body + 340
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f550d _pthread_start + 375
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4bf9 thread_start + 13

#6. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d62da16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f6589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2  libc++.1.dylib                 0x7fff6b431d43 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 93
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x7fff49316ab5 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 117
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x7fff493169a0 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 96
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x7fff493165c9 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 361
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x7fff49316359 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 9
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x7fff49316698 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 40
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f5661 _pthread_body + 340
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f550d _pthread_start + 375
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4bf9 thread_start + 13

#7. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d62420a mach_msg_trap + 10
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d623724 mach_msg + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff456a1785 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff456a0ad7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff456a0153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5  CFNetwork                      0x7fff447eae84 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 722
6  Foundation                     0x7fff477ab1f8 __NSThread__start__ + 1197
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f5661 _pthread_body + 340
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f550d _pthread_start + 375
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4bf9 thread_start + 13

#8. com.apple.NSEventThread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d62420a mach_msg_trap + 10
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7fff6d623724 mach_msg + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff456a1785 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
3  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff456a0ad7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
4  CoreFoundation                 0x7fff456a0153 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
5  AppKit                         0x7fff42d78fc4 _NSEventThread + 184
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f5661 _pthread_body + 340
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f550d _pthread_start + 375
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff6d7f4bf9 thread_start + 13
```

I've tried using the MacSymbolicator app, but I haven't had any success. It says UDIDs don't match even though I used the dsym for the archive build. ItunesConnect hasn't reported the crash at all. Not sure why crashlytics reported it, but not itunesconnect. Don't know what else I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions on macOS are a real pain, because by default AppKit swallows the important information - the exception backtrace. I've opened a number of bugs with Apple about this, and I encourage you to do the same. UIKit is much, much better behaved.

Based on the stacktraces you've included, it looks like you have correctly configured Crashlytics for exception capture on macOS. But, just in case, their documentation is available [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/os-x.html).

Despite that, it looks like you do not have the exception stack trace. It will not be possible to get useful information out of this report without it. After verifying that you've got things setup right, I might reach out to the Crashlytics support people to see if there's something else going wrong.